# jaxb unmarshaller reading values as 0

Tags: java, jaxb

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BatchwisePricingJob.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

StringReader reader = new StringReader(batchprice.toString());

BatchwisePricingJob batch = (BatchwisePricingJob) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
ArrayList<Price> pricingOfProduct = batch.getPricingOfProduct();

int i = 0;
for (Price price : pricingOfProduct) {
    i++;
    System.out.println("customer id:" + i + " " + price.getCustomerId());
    System.out.println("material id:" + i + " " + price.getMaterialId());
}
```

also given `@XmlElement` annotaion to getters/setters but then it throws the exception for `Illegealannotationexception`

```
Class has two properties of the same name "customerId"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.Price.getCustomerId()
        at com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.Price
        at private java.util.ArrayList com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.BatchwisePricingJob.pricingOfProduct
        at com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.BatchwisePricingJob
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private int com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.Price.customerId
        at com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.Price
        at private java.util.ArrayList com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.BatchwisePricingJob.pricingOfProduct
        at com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.BatchwisePricingJob
```

Comment: In the future please format your code and use the code (`{}`) button when you paste your code into the editor. Without seeing your XML and the bound class there's not a lot we can do except guess; that is a waste of our time and yours.

Answer (score 0):

The values being unmarshalled will be `null` if the XML document does not match your mappings.  The easiest thing to do is populate your object model and then marshal it out to see the XML that corresponds to your current mappings.  You can use `@XmlElement` and `@XmlAttribute` to specify name you want to map to if the desired one differs from the default.

You will see the following exception if you map both the field and its corresponding property.  The following article will help you:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

```
Class has two properties of the same name "customerId"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.Price.getCustomerId()
        at com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.Price
        at private java.util.ArrayList com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.BatchwisePricingJob.pricingOfProduct
        at com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.BatchwisePricingJob
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private int com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.Price.customerId
        at com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.Price
        at private java.util.ArrayList com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.BatchwisePricingJob.pricingOfProduct
        at com.efl.efms.batch.ws.data.batchwisePricing.BatchwisePricingJob
```